# Google Search in c# windows application

Tags: c#, google-search-console

Sorry for my bad English.
I need to add a google search to my c# windows application therefore I added a textbox and a button to my form when user click on button application sends search query to google.
As you have seen google has a very good auto complete for its search textbox.
Is there any way for adding that auto complete to my application?

Comment: textbox has autocomplete property

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can query the URL:

```
http://suggestqueries.google.com/complete/search?client=firefox&q=YOURQUERY
```

For example, `http://suggestqueries.google.com/complete/search?client=firefox&q=justin` will return:

```
["justin",["justin bieber","justin timberlake","justin tv","justin timberlake tour","justin boots","justin blackmon","justin baldoni","justin bieber twitter","justin long","justin moore"]]
```

Comment: Hi dear jack. Can you please more explain? How can I bind my listBox to this query?

Comment: you should use json.net to get list of suggested words and bind it to listbox

Answer (score 1):

There is a `AutoComplete` property for `TextBox`.
For the implementation, you can check the following [link](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/516606/HowplustoplusimplementplusAutoCompleteplusinplusTe)

Comment: Hi and thanks for your answer. I think your link is for web applications isn't?

Comment: @user1425882 The link is for WinForms application, also whether you want to implement the auto completion feature in a web application or WinForms the basic concept remains the same.